# Create page with single script file given to browser using react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to just send the client a single line like so:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

which is valid HTML5.

I then want to build the page back up with React.js. E.g. (note modified code, I had some errors in my simplified code),

```
React = require('react');
e = React.createElement;
App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return e('html', null, 
            (e('head', null, 
              e('script', {src: '/js/app.js'})), 
            e('body', null, 'hello!')));
  }
});
React.render(e(App, null), document.documentElement);
```

the resulting DOM:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body data-reactid=".0.0">hello!</body>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags in React. Browser renders them anyway if they are missing in received HTML document.

All you need to do is:

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({displayName: "App",
  render: function(){
    return (
        React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, World")
    );
  }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    React.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.body);
});
```

Also, instead of tricks like `e = React.createElement` [try using `jsx`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) which makes code much more readable:

```
var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
        <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    );
  }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    React.render(<App />, document.body);
});
```

Comment: Since I'm just sending `<script src="/js/app.js"></script>` if I render to `document.body` it will error out on me since the browser hasn't created the `body` tag yet. Also, I will want to add `css` references to the `head` tag. I'm not using JSX because I'm writing in `LiveScript`, I just converted it to `JavaScript` to make it easier for others to comment on.

Comment: Also, I'm coming from using `Mithril.js`, so although I'm finding similarities, there's enough differences that I'm having a hard time figure this out.

Comment: That's why I've added `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to make sure that `document.body` is ready. What kind of error do you have in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. I'll try it out.

Comment: OK, that works, I guess I can put the CSS files in the body, not as clean as I would like to do it but it works.